# How to find whether a Point lies inside a Polygon using ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

We want to find whether a Point lies inside a Polygon.

```
var point = new esri.geometry.Point(-85.91,25.68,this.parent.esriMap.spatialReference);    

var polygon = new esri.geometry.Polygon(this.parent.esriMap.spatialReference);

polygon .addRing([contains the lat and long]);

boolean result=polygon .contains(point);
```

The moment I add the contains method call (`polygon .contains(point);`), I get an error stating that ESRIMapViewer does not have a constructor.  ESRIMapViewer.js is the file which contains the above code.

Answer (score 3):

i've posted a working sample [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/pointInPolygon.html)

```
var polygon = new Polygon(new SpatialReference({wkid:4326}));
polygon.addRing([[-120,30],[-120,40],[-110,40],[-110,30],[-120,30]])

var point = new Point(-115, 35, {"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326 }})
polygon.contains(point); //returns true
```

are you sure that the SpatialReference you are digging out of your map is WGS84 and not WebMercator?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer.There was one mistake in my code.boolean result=..... I changed it to var(it does accept the boolean data type) and also gave the proper spatial reference.Now I have another problem.When I hard code the lat and long as below it works polygon.addRing([[-120,30],[-120,40],[-110,40],[-110,30],[-120,30]]); When I copy the lat and long to a variable,the contains method returns false. var val="[[-120,30],[-120,40],[-110,40],[-110,30],[-120,30]]";polygon.addRing(val)

Comment: your variable should be a real array, not a string, so drop the trailing and leading quotes.

Comment: Thanks John.I removed the trailing and leading quotes and it worked.Thanks a ton.

Comment: Hi John Thanks a lot for your time and for your repiles.I have run into another issue.I get the latitude and longitude from two different entities.Hence I concatenate them as below var greenArr=new Array();var greenPolygon = new esri.geometry.Polygon(this.parent.esriMap.spatialReference); if (type == 'Green') {var coords = '[' + parseFloat(longitude)+ ','+ parseFloat(latitude)+ ']'; greenArr += coords + ","; } greenArr="["+ greenArr +"]"; greenPolygon.addRing(greenArr); Here the contains method is not working.it returns false always

Comment: please give me credit for answering your original question and post this new question in a seperate thread with your code wrapped in the appropriate tags and I will take a look.